# Multithreading libraries for Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows, linux, multithreading

Excluding Cocoa (and its `NSThread`), what multithreading libraries would you recommend?

The application's engine must run on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, MacOS, iPhone), and  be multithreaded. Abstracting the library to compile against platform-specific MT libraries is possible, but incurs an extra layer of overhead and complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSOperation works fine. As an added bonus you get a thread pool for free, and can setup a dependency chain between operations.

Answer (score 0):

How  about something in the C library area?
e.g libapr: http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__os__thread.html

or glib?
http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Grand Central which was recently open-sourced: http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/